# Hide right-sidebar on specific node/module

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I am setting up my first drupal (6) site and so far I like the system.

I've now run into a problem however: to give the content more space I want to hide the right-sidebar (with the navigation menu etc.) on every page from a specific module (or also fine: for a specific node/view from the module)

The only way I've come up with is to add some CSS to the module CSS files, but this doesn't seem very clean to me since I would need to redo it on every update (also the module uses 5 CSS files for different views)

Is there a better way to do it?

To be clear: I don't want to just hide a block, I want to hide the whole sidebar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmmm. Is this a custom module or something commonly available? Some modules allow you to create custom tpl.php files (see the [theming guide](http://drupal.org/documentation/theme)) for them. This might quickly solve your problem.

If you are theming a *node*, then it is significantly easier. You can theme a specific type of node by naming convention (again via .tpl.php files in your theme). You can check out [how to do that here](http://www.hankpalan.com/blog/drupal-themes/theming-node-drupalthe-easy-way).

Definitely check out the theming guide, since you will probably want to create your own theme instead of hacking on one of the core themes (not recommended). Typically you can copy /themes/garland into /sites/all/themes/my_garland, switch your site's theme to that and then make whatever changes you need (otherwise you'll have to reapply changes every time you update core).

Finally, you can check for path arguments (which seemed weird to me at first) if you want to do things in PHP that are more complex (see the [arg](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--path.inc/function/arg/6) function). If this is your first Drupal site, you may also need to know [how to include css programatically](http://drupal.org/node/134402).

Good luck! Drupal is a fun and interesting product.

Comment: It is something commonly available, the Calendar (http://drupal.org/project/calendar) module to be exact. But thanks for all the pointers! I can definitly work with that.

Answer (score 1):

You can configure the block visibility for each individual block and path in your website (admin/build/block). Under 'Configure'/'Page specific visibility settings'/'Show block on specific pages' you can set the navigation menu block not to be displayed for some specific routes. If a sidebar has no blocks to display it will hide itself allowing more space for the content.

Comment: I tried that but the menu didn't hide. Maybe it does on the default themes but not on mine.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the Context module, with it you can, among other things, set rules for each block/menu where and when i should be shown (or not). You could also do this the way Josep explained but with Context you get more options.

And as Josep said when there are no blocks active in the sidebar it should disappear automatically, if not check your page.tpl.php it should have something like this in it:

```
   <?php if ($right): ?>  
    <div id="sidebar-right">
      <div id="sidebar-right-inner"> <?php print $right; ?> </div>
    </div>
   <?php endif; ?>
```

So if there is nothing in the Right region it doesn't display the sidebar. Maybe you have to change the name of the region, depending how they are called in you template.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you already got the answer or a way to fix your problem.

There is a simple way to fix your problem. Here's [a link](http://www.templatemonster.com/help/drupal-7-x-how-to-remove-sidebar-from-the-node-single-pages.html).